# After install COM AddIn, test connect in Excel, got bluescreen

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, shared, minidump

COM Excel AddIn, C#, VS 2008, 
Excel COM Addin, tested on test VM, works fine
Customer installed and got blue screen, have no clue why. 
Following is what customer got. Can someone help? I have no idea what's this, what causes this. 
not sure if this is caused by my addin or something is wrong on customer's PC.

thanks

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [c:\windows\minidump\Mini050911-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

WARNING: Inaccessible path: 'c:\windows\i386'
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: c:\windows\i386
Windows XP Kernel Version 2600 (Service Pack 3) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.101209-1647
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0x804d7000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0x8055d720
Debug session time: Mon May  9 09:47:22.099 2011 (UTC - 5:00)
System Uptime: 2 days 15:09:35.096
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
..............................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
...........................

---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1000007F, {8, 80042000, 0, 0}

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for igxpmp32.sys**
 ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for igxpmp32.sys
Unable to load image igxpdx32.DLL, Win32 error 0n2
 **WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for igxpdx32.DLL
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for igxpdx32.DLL
Probably caused by : igxpmp32.sys ( igxpmp32+44184 )

### Followup: MachineOwner

0: kd> !analyze -v

---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP_M (1000007f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
bugcheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: 80042000
Arg3: 00000000
Arg4: 00000000

### Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  EXCEL.EXE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 805362cb to 80535dc8

STACK_TEXT:
97d0d004 805362cb 97d0d01c 97d0d0d8 8aeec418 nt!ExpFindCurrentThread+0x8
97d0d028 8062c345 8055a1e0 00000001 8063791f nt!ExAcquireResourceSharedLite+0x51
97d0d034 8063791f 97d0d0d8 8aeec418 97d0d0cc nt!CmpLockRegistry+0x27
97d0d06c 805bfe5b e5eb5708 00000001 97d0d0a4 nt!CmpSecurityMethod+0x17
97d0d0ac 805c01c8 e5eb5708 97d0d0d8 e5eb5704 nt!ObpGetObjectSecurity+0x99
97d0d0dc 8062f28f e5eb5708 8786ddc0 00000001 nt!ObCheckObjectAccess+0x2c
97d0d128 8062ff30 e1036758 003778f0 00000000 nt!CmpDoOpen+0x2d5
97d0d328 805bf488 003778f0 00000000 8786ddc0 nt!CmpParseKey+0x5a6
97d0d3a0 805bba14 00000000 97d0d3e0 00000240 nt!ObpLookupObjectName+0x53c
97d0d3f4 80625696 00000000 8aeec418 00000000 nt!ObOpenObjectByName+0xea
97d0d4f0 8054167c 97d0d810 82000000 97d0d594 nt!NtOpenKey+0x1c8
97d0d4f0 80500699 97d0d810 82000000 97d0d594 nt!KiFastCallEntry+0xfc
97d0d574 805e701e 97d0d810 82000000 97d0d594 nt!ZwOpenKey+0x11
97d0d7e4 805e712a 00000002 805e70a0 00000000 nt!RtlpGetRegistryHandleAndPath+0x27a
97d0d82c 805e73e3 97d0d84c 00000014 97d0dba0 nt!RtlpQueryRegistryGetBlockPolicy+0x2e
97d0d854 805e79eb 00000003 e3fba72c 00000014 nt!RtlpQueryRegistryDirect+0x4b
97d0d8a4 805e7f10 e3fba72c 00000003 97d0d930 nt!RtlpCallQueryRegistryRoutine+0x369
97d0db40 b92f8184 00000005 e5eb4a28 97d0dba0 nt!RtlQueryRegistryValues+0x482
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
97d0dbe8 b92bd85b 00000005 877fe5f4 877fe6f4 igxpmp32+0x44184
97d0e260 b92b9a7b 8938b358 97d0e290 00000000 igxpmp32+0x985b
97d0e274 b9496729 8938b358 97d0e290 00000a0c igxpmp32+0x5a7b
97d0e338 804ef19f 8938b040 8781d6b8 0000080c VIDEOPRT!pVideoPortDispatch+0xabf
97d0e348 bf86ebbd 97d0e610 bf6e6cdc 00000014 nt!IopfCallDriver+0x31
97d0e378 bf86ec37 8938b040 00232150 97d0e3f8 win32k!GreDeviceIoControl+0x93
97d0e39c bf376769 8938b040 00232150 97d0e3f8 win32k!EngDeviceIoControl+0x1f
97d0f624 bf3b9f79 8938b040 bf6a593c bf6a5960 igxpdx32+0x8769
97d0f6b8 804fb540 00000002 00000002 97d0f6e8 igxpdx32+0x4bf79
97d0f77c 804fb488 00000000 02d0f818 97d0f7b4 nt!KeFlushSingleTb+0xae
97d0f7a8 805361db 97d0f7c0 bf3ab93b 00000000 nt!KeFlushMultipleTb+0x10e
97d0f7e0 bf3752ae 97d0f898 97d0f8b4 97d0fd28 nt!ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite+0x67
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 igxpdx32+0x72ae

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
igxpmp32+44184
b92f8184 ??              ???

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  12

SYMBOL_NAME:  igxpmp32+44184

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: igxpmp32

IMAGE_NAME:  igxpmp32.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4b47be93

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_igxpmp32+44184

BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_igxpmp32+44184

Followup: MachineOwner

Answer (score 2):

Before diving into the actual call stack, I'd advise to do some further forensics as to determine whether it is *actually* your addin that is causing the BSOD. The Intel Graphics drivers are known for their tendency to end up in a BSOD mess.

1. Ask if the BSOD problem goes away once your addin is uninstalled.
2. Ask if the customer is willing to install more recent (or older) video drivers.
3. Ask if the customer to run Windows' Memory Diagnostics to look for bad RAM.

Comment: @Paul, thank you. Before I get to customer. Just somehting customer saw, maybe it makes some sense to you.  According to customer, he install/uninsall my AddIn a few times before it shows up in Excel Menu. Then he went to connection screen, he typed in connection string(web service url), clicked OK. Then he immediately got blue screen.  thank you so much!

Comment: The Addin installation behaviour you describe is usually percepted by customers that have old Excel processes floating around, I assume your installation process itself is rather trivial? The immediate bsod could be explained by your addin starting to actually do stuff, allocating more memory, and hitting broken memory modules (or badly allocated by Intels shared video memory management, or whatever those drivers do). As an alternative theory, did you thoroughly test in your VM what happens when users enter wrong/invalid URLs into that connection string dialog?

Comment: I can tell you with 100% certainty that the Excel add-in is not directly the culprit. At the very best, it *happens* to use some feature that causes the Intel driver to crash, but I think this is extremely unlikely

Comment: @Paul-Jan, yes, installation is trivial. I tested with invalid URL on VM, it fails to conect and gives expected error msg.  I justed try to break addin, I entered a URL sth. like http://msdn.microsoft.com\ , excel crashes. but no blue screen. Do you think that will cause blue screen issue on clien? I'll fix the crash with invalid URL

Comment: @Paul-Jan, how to run Memory Diagnostics to look for bad RAM? I will look for this. Just want to make sure I know how to do it before telling customer. thanks

Comment: @Paul-Betts, thanks for the info. It makes me feel a bit better otherwise I feel so bad that my code crashes client's machine.

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be a bad video driver, but this really looks more like bad RAM. Your Excel add-in is just the victim.

Comment: thank you so much. Can you point some doc or link for me to get more info?

Comment: I can't sadly, I've learned to read memory dumps from internal-to-MS references over the years... The help file that comes with WinDbg is actually one of the best docs on this subject, it's quite thorough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will take a look at WinDbg doc

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at these links.  You can likely resolve the issue by updating the video or other drivers or by uninstalling this KB.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2393802 (see Known Issues)
http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2011/03/23/stop-error-0x0000007f-or-0x1000007f-after-installing-ms11-011-kb2393802.aspx